# How do I design this EER diagram?

Tags: sql-server

I want to create a database following the following specifications: 
A well known bicycle company stores its data in a special database.

Company has customers and
products.

- All customers have a unique customer_id.
- Customers are categorized as foreign customers or domestic customers. A customer must
  be foreign or domestic, and can not belong to both of the categories at the same time.
- Foreign customers are identified by their unique id, currency, company name and address
  composed of city state and zipcode.
- Domestic customers are identified by their unique id, name and address. Domestic
  customers may have more than one address information.
- Products are identified by unique product_id, model, type and price.
- Only two type of products are produced in this company. These product types are Bike and
  Mountain Bike.
- Each bike has color and cycle attributes.
- Each mountain bike has cycling team attribute.
- A product may belong to at least one of this types. Moreover it may belong to both of them
  at the same time.
- Customers may request products. And a product may be requested by more than one
  customer, also it may not be requested by any customer at all.
- When a product is requested or ordered by a customer; request id, request type and request
  content information is stored.

I asked about the composite key address and I got 2 possible choices right now: Create a table for address or create city, state and zipcode keys and add a constraint named address. However, it says that a domestic customer may have more than one address information. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Do you already draw or prepare a ERD or draft? What issue you are actually facing?

Comment: @mkRabbani I've partially draw the EERD, but I don't know how to link the adress attribute to the diagram. Because; in the question it says a foreign customer has address as a composite key. So I add the composite key to the foreign customer entity. However, it says that a domestic customer may have more than one address address information. Now, what does that even mean?

Comment: You can think something like - TableName: Customer (Columns: id,country_id,city_id,other_address_line). country_id and city_id is FK reference to table country and city. I am suggesting different city table considering multiple outlet in the same city.

Comment: @mkRabbani Thanks for the responses. So just to clarify I want to ask again if you'll allow. There is this composite attribute address(city, state, zipcode). You're suggesting that I make a table for city, state and zipcode, furthermore I add those attributes to the customer table and make them foreign key to get the information from the tables I created. Did I understand correctly? Now I want to ask this: e.g. a customer has phone_number attribute. A customer may have one or more phone numbers. Is it possible to add 2 phone numbers in one row to the customer table? Phone number is multivalued

Comment: You understand correctly. Regarding phone number, this is not standard practice to have multiple value in a single column. you may have 2/3 column like 'phone_1','Phone_3','Phone_3'. But again the best option if you can have a table Phone_directory with column 'customer_id' and 'phone_number'.

Comment: If you can restrict a company to at best 2 phone number, then add 2 column in the table for better management. But for unlimited phone number, you can add the suggested table.

Comment: @mkRabbani Thanks again but if I do that, wouldn't it be like this: say a customer has 2 phone numbers. There will be 2 rows for the same customer with exact same values for each attribute except the phone number. Isn't that so? The thing is there is this multivalued attribute thing thaught at school but when I search how to implement it into code noone gives a specific answer nor does anyone know the answer. Why is that, I'm confused.

Comment: Yes, both option has positive and negative impact. I this you can think about 2 or 3 column for phone per customer.

Comment: @mkRabbani Yeah you are right. But I don't think it would be a good idea to have 2-3 rows per customer :) Thanks anyways.